# When do we practically need 'explicit xvalues'?

Tags: c++, c++11

The definition of **xvalue** is as follows:

> — An xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually near the end of its lifetime (so that its resources may be moved, for example). An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references (8.3.2). [ Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is an rvalue reference is an xvalue. —end example ]

Will we ever fall into where we practically need to use a function whose return type is an rvalue reference, which is an xvalue?

```
const int && Foo()
{
    // ...
}
```

Move semantics take an rvalue reference as a parameter, not a return value. So I don't think that's the case.

Comment: what do you mean by "explicit" in the title?

Comment: @M.M If I write a function that returns an xvalue and I am 'aware of' it, and that's intended by me, I'd say that's explicit even though there is no syntatic keyword to indicate xvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning rvalue references can be of use for functions that already take rvalues as parameters. A simple example:

```
struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(X&& other) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
    X(X const&) = delete;
    void log(std::string const& s){ std::cout << "log: " << s << "\n"; }
};

void sink(X&& x) { 
    x.log("sink"); 
}

X&& passOn(X&& in) {
    in.log("pass");
    return std::move(in);
}

X moveOn(X&& in) {
    in.log("move");
    return std::move(in);
}

int main() {
    sink(passOn(X()));
    std::cout << "===============================\n";
    sink(moveOn(X()));
}
```

[Live demo →](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b44626687977e15)

The second function will call the move constructor to create the returned object, while the first will pass on the reference it already got. This is more useful if we don't return the original reference but instead a reference to a part of the referred object, e.g.

```
template<class T>
T&& getHead(std::vector<T>&& input) {
    return std::move(input.front());
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 Not moving here would call the deleted copy constructor. I am not sure if NRVO would apply at all, since there is no object inside the function.

Comment: Useful for perfectly forwarded filter functions. +1!

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) is — the result of `std::move` execution is an xvalue. Other than that it is hard to tell since in the main returning a reference from the function is a bad thing most of the time. But maybe someone will come up with another clever usage of such a function.

Comment: @DeanSeo, indeed but you can't use rvalue reference in the return type for anything else except casting since returning a reference(no matter what type it is) from the function is wrong except if it is const and const rvalue reference is useless

Comment: Sorry for deleteting my previous comment. Btw, 'const rvalue reference that is being returned' is an xvalue. So recursively, returning xvalues is practically useless, you saying? :p

Comment: @DeanSeo, what I'm saying is that returning a reference to the thing that is created on the stack within a function is incorrect. So I see no usage example when we can use an rvalue reference as the return type except for the case which we have with `std::move`(we got something from the outside and returned an rvalue ref to it). It doesn't mean there is not such a usage — language features are rediscovered again and again. But for now I heard of nothing in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

> Will we ever fall into where we practically need to use a function whose return type is an rvalue reference, which is an xvalue?

It used in container classes, for instance `tuple` has a `get` overload that looks like this:

```
template< std::size_t I, class... Types >
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...> >::type&&
    get( tuple<Types...>&& t );
```

I assume that `std::optional` and `std::variant` in C++17 will both have a similar overloads.

Granted, the only point is to avoid to type `std::move` in some very specific situations, like:

```
 auto x = std::get<1>( f() );
```

Where `f` returns a tuple by value.

Comment: A great example of how to save even move constructors where they aren't needed (i.e. theoretically it could have just returned the xvalues converted to prvalues, but that would require, unnecessarily, either a move or a copy constructor, which also aren't always available).